# Jquery Nice scroll not working

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

I am using Jquery nice Scroll bar for div, but when content of div increases dynamically its not showing scroll bar. Windows default scroll bar works fine if i remove nice scroll. 
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Html

```
<div id="div-to-scroll">
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var nice = $("#div-to-scroll").getNiceScroll();
    $("#div-to-scroll").niceScroll();
    $("#div-to-scroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

this is my code sample.

Comment: sry ;-) i tought the current code state :-)

Comment: hmm should work with simple $("#div-to-scroll").niceScroll(); ... strange

Comment: id or class div-to-scroll ? ;-)

Comment: sorry its id i forgot to change it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally this works for me.

```
$("#div-to-scroll").scroll(function(){
  $("#div-to-scroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Answer (score 11):

for me works just with

```
$("#div-to-scroll").mouseover(function() {
    $("#div-to-scroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Comment: Where did the `mouseover` come from?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: new function found!**

```
 var setScroll = function(i) {
        if($(i).length>0)
        $(i).niceScroll().updateScrollBar();
}
```

Call this function to Update niceScroll

```
setScroll(".classWithNiceScroll");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some possible reasons:
1- Maybe you forgot to specify your div height. fix your div Height.
2- also if your div is float in width fix that width too.
**Remmember that your DIV STYLE should have: `overflow-y: hidden;`**
**UPDATE**
try using resize() function every time you scroll down:

```
$("div-to-scroll").slideDown(function(){
  $("div-to-scroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Comment: Yes that all i have done. the thing is when window load it works but after i start to append content its not working.

Comment: @keyuratcodebins.com what happen after you append content? does it stop scrolling or it show all the content at the same time?

Comment: @keyuratcodebins.com try using resize() function every time you scroll down

Comment: I have the same problem, I found that if I switch tabs on chrome and go back it starts working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("html").mouseover(function() {
    $("html").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

To get the scroll bar on full body

Comment: The 2nd line has an extra `#` .

Comment: @Raptor Yes, Just follow the syntax. (Selector is immaterial here)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
// Scroll X Axis 
$("#mydiv").getNiceScroll()[0].doScrollLeft(x, duration);
// Scroll Y Axis - 
$("#mydiv").getNiceScroll()[0].doScrollTop(y, duration);
```

or:

```
// Scroll X Axis 
$("#mydiv").getNiceScroll(0).doScrollLeft(x, duration);
// Scroll Y Axis - 
$("#mydiv").getNiceScroll(0).doScrollTop(y, duration);
```

Note `[0]` after `getNiceScroll()`