# Javascript niceScroll resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, nicescroll

I am using jQuery plugin version 3.10 to use custom scrollbars. I have numerous horizontal slides and each uses its own custom scrollbar. I want to include javascript .onclick function that expands text. However, the scrollbar does not appear when I expand the text and it overflows. I am using the following code to select the headings which should have the onclick function (tag "h3", class "click"):

```
function toggleNext(el) {
 var next=el.nextSibling;
 while(next.nodeType != 1) next=next.nextSibling;
 next.style.display=((next.style.display=="none") ? "block" : "none");
}

function getElementsByTagAndClassName(tag,cname) {
 var tags=document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
 var cEls=new Array();
 for (i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
  var rE = new RegExp("(^|\s)" + cname + "(\s|$)");
   if (rE.test(tags[i].className)) {
   cEls.push(tags[i]);
   }
  }
 return cEls;
}
function toggleNextByTagAndClassName(tag,cname) {
 var ccn="clicker";
 clickers=getElementsByTagAndClassName(tag,cname);
 for (i=0; i<clickers.length; i++) {
  clickers[i].className+=" "+ccn;
  clickers[i].onclick=function() {toggleNext(this)}
  toggleNext(clickers[i]);
 }
}
window.onload=function(){toggleNextByTagAndClassName('h3','click')}
```

Example of HTML:

```
<article class="slide" id="lorem">
<div class="inner">
<h3 class="click">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<div class="content">
<p>Sample text, is sample text, is sample text</p>
</div>
```

I know from previous research that I've done that I have to call the resize function from niceScroll jQuery plugin, which is as follows.

```
$(name-of-div).getNiceScroll().resize()
```

I have tried using the resize function with the name-of-div as content, however this does not yield the expected results. Please help if you can. I am not sure how to implement the two together.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if understood what's going on but I had a similar problem. Try using the resize() inside a setTimeout.

Note that the "name-of-div" must be the name of the scroll's container.
The jQuery code would looks like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('name-of-div').getNiceScroll().resize()
}, 500);
```

I used 500 as an example, but if your div's text expand while animate you must use a number greater then your div animation, and of course, the code must execute after all interactions

Answer (score 0):

See the **question below**. There are two answers and both work for me. Basically, I have applied **the second method**(See the second answer) suggested there. Because, it works instantly and the first method doesn't seem to work instantly after the div has been resized.

[Jquery Nice scroll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862656/jquery-nice-scroll-not-working/11876895)